# Calling child thread method from parent thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parent-child

I have a Chat program (running on android) that runs a ui (Chat_client) and then creates an ChatThread that runs communication. I have managed making the client thread call a parent method (using post) but not vsv. I want the parent to call the send method on the client side after the user pushes send button. Help greatly appreciated!

//BUTTON SEND METHOD in parent class. (Chat-thread is running already)

```
public void send (View view) {
    //THIS IS NOT WORKING
    chatThread.sendLine(userInput.getText().toString());

}
```

//Method in child class

```
public void sendLine (String line){
        to_server.println(line);
 }
```

Comment: to_server writes to the socket.

Comment: Why not create a `HandlerThread` and post messages to that Threads handler.

Comment: Ok please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some research I arrived at the following solution.

The child thread opens the socket and then creates another thread that reads from socket. The child thread has handler and looper (message que) to which the UI thread sends messages to send through the socket.

Voila!